# Rumors told between $n+1$ people

Tags: probability

In a town of $(n + 1)$ inhabitants, a person tells a rumor to
a second person, who in turn repeats it to a third person, etc. At
each step the recipient of the rumor is chosen at random from the
$n$ people available.

(a) Find the probability that the rumor will be told $r$ times without:

(i.) returning to the originator;

(ii.) being repeated to any person.

Here's what I did:

> (i.) For the first person, the probability is $1$ because they are the originator and can not tell to themselves. For the second, we can tell it to one of the $(n-1)$ people because they can't tell it to themselves nor to the originator, and so for the third. Thus: $1 * {(\frac{n-1}{n})}^{r-1}$. Note that considering that a person can not tell it to themselves then I devided the fraction by $n$ and not $n+1$.
>
> (ii.) For the first person, again, we have probability of $1$. Then $n-1$ options for the second (not to themselves, and not to the orignator: $n+1 - 1 -1 = n-1$), then $n-2$ for the third (not to themselves, not to the first, and not to the previous: $n+1 - 1 - 1 -1 = n-2$. etc r times.

Is this good?

Comment: I think (i) is fine, and (ii) should be $1\cdot \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n}\cdots \frac{n-(r-1)}{n}$, which is of course what you concluded more explicitly stated.

Comment: That's what I said also for ii, but I just didnt write the full probability, only the options :)
Thank you.

Comment: Why? One can't say the rumor to themselves so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Meow stated in a comment, your results are fine.